# Set environment variable (TZ) for all startup scripts and inittab

Tags: environment-variables, startup, busybox, timezone, busybox-init

I'm working on an embedded Linux system and looking for a way to set the time zone for all processes.

The question is: Is there any possibility to set the `TZ` environment variable at boot time (init scripts) so that all other init scripts have `TZ` set at start up?

The system is based on the BusyBox tools. I tried a script in `/etc/profile.d/` folder.

```
export TZ="GMT-1"
```

But the init scripts do not have the variable set.

The only way I see is that *all* start scripts set this variable by themselves.
Are there other solutions for this problem?

Comment: The system timezone is often set via a symbolic link from something like `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Zone/SubZone` to `/etc/localtime` - but I don't know enough about your config / setup to know if that's viable.

Comment: @EightBitTony That works with Glibc, but not with some of the libc that are common on embedded systems.

Comment: How about /etc/TZ ?

Comment: So actually, what we need to know is which libc @Klaus is using in their embedded system.  It's really a question about libc, rather than busybox.

Comment: @EightBitTony glibc version is 2.21

Comment: I know `/etc/localtime`. But it is hard to find the correct `tzfile` programmatically.

Comment: If it's `glibc`, then create a permanent symbolic link from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Zone/SubZone` to `/etc/localtime` once?  Or is the filesystem read only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system uses BusyBox init, and it doesn't have `/etc/inittab`, then it runs `/etc/init.d/rcS` at boot time. If this is a shell script, just add the environment definitions you want there. If this isn't a shell script, you can change your build to rename `/etc/init.d/rcS.bin`, and create a shell script `/etc/init.d/rcS` that ends with `exec /etc/init.d/rcS.bin`. Of course, if you've changed the path `/etc/init.d/rcS` in the build configuration, adapt for that. Environment variables defined there will apply to all daemons, but not to shells started on consoles.

If you have `/etc/inittab`, check what it contains. The documentation is in the [sample file](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/examples/inittab). You can replace entries that run `somecommand` by `/usr/bin/env TZ=GMT-1 somecommand` .

That's the quick-and-dirty way, but in most cases you'd want to allow the end user to configure the timezone, so it should be stored in a separate file. In that case, go through a shell wrapper (or the `rcS` script) and use some code like

```
export TZ="$(cat /etc/TZ.txt)"
```

Note that depending on your libc, there may or may not be a better way of setting the timezone, e.g. writing the timezone rules in `/etc/TZ` for uClibc.

Comment: With your answer we decide to do the following: The system has a `export-tz` script. This script we source in `/etc/defaults/rcS`.  So all the  init scripts have `TZ`. `/etc/profile.d/` has a link to `export-tz`. So every user has `TZ`. For each `/etc/inittab` entry, the `TZ` needs, we source the `export-tz` script.